# Getting SonarQube major Vulnerabilities in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

In my Springboot application project using Java Script. I have written a code like this,

```
 document.getElementById("pendingARModID").action = "annualReviewApproval?status="+ status, 
 {penArKeys : penArKeysArray};
```

Getting Sonar qube vulnerabilities in Jenkins pipeline.

> Issue type:
> Any statement (other than a null statement, which means a statement containing only a semicolon ;) which has no side effect and does not result in a change of control flow will normally indicate a programming error, and therefore should be refactored.

Comment: Its unclear what you want to achieve. Could you please give some more information.

Comment: @SouravAtta In my .js file these piece of code giving Sonar qube major issue, how to write this code by this we can achieve on Sonar Vulnerabilities. Issue type given in description.